# Average price of scraped item on ebay using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I get the average price from a list of scraped items' prices from ebay?

This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession

link = "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=5035224123933&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=EAN5035224123933&_osacat=0"

req = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
with requests.Session() as c:
    
     soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')
     lists = soup.find_all('li', class_="s-item s-item__pl-on-bottom s-item--watch-at-corner")
     for list in(lists):
        price=float(list.find('span', class_="s-item__price").text.replace('£',''))
        avg = sum(price)/len(price)
```

I've tried:

```
avg = sum(price)/len(price)
```

But it gives an error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your line before says `price=float(..)` - so yes, `price` is a floating point number and thus trying to `sum()` and `len()` it doesn't make sense to Python. You probably wanted to put all those prices in a list (e.g. `prices`) and then compute `sum(prices) / len(prices)`

Comment: @Grismar i'm really new on that , could you please let me know how can i put all those prices in a list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the rest of your code works correctly, and retrieves the prices you need, the problem is with this:

```
    for list in(lists):
        price=float(list.find('span', class_="s-item__price").text.replace('£',''))
        avg = sum(price)/len(price)
```

You say `price=float(..)` - so yes, `price` is a floating point number and thus trying to `sum()` and `len()` it on the next line doesn't make sense to Python. You probably wanted to put all those prices in a list (e.g. `prices`) and then compute `sum(prices) / len(prices)`

Something like:

```
    prices = []
    for list in lists:
        prices.append(float(list.find('span', class_="s-item__price").text.replace('£','')))
    avg = sum(prices) / len(prices)
```

To understand why you got that error, consider:

```
>>> sum(1.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
>>> len(1.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

So, you see those operations don't work on invidual values, they work on an iterable with a length (like a list). Another clue about your original code is that the computation of the average was inside the loop (indented), but you only want to compute the average once, not for every price.

Answer (score 2):

You need to store a list of the prices, and then compute the average after the loop which adds each prise to the list. Also, it's bad practice to name variables that conflict with built-in names like `list`, and in general you should have more descriptive variable names. In this case I suggest `items` for `lists` and `item` for `list`. Additionally, you don't need parentheses around the target of `in`.

```py
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession

link = "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=5035224123933&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=EAN5035224123933&_osacat=0"

req = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
with requests.Session() as c:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html5lib')
    items = soup.find_all('li', class_="s-item s-item__pl-on-bottom s-item--watch-at-corner")
    prices = []
    for item in items:
        prices.append(float(item.find('span', class_="s-item__price").text.replace('£','')))
    avg = sum(price)/len(price)
```

Comment: I can't test this due to the fact that I don't have requests_html, but it should work.

Comment: Why not just pip install it? It’s the same namespace in pypi

Comment: @m9m Just did, it works